# Normal closure in a perfect group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a perfect group and $H$ the conjugate closure of $B\le G$. Is there any way to tell when $H$ is perfect too? Thanks!

Comment: a trivial case, if $G$ is simple then $G$ is perfect, and any nontrivial closure is equal to $G$ itself as a result it is perfect. This idea may be used to solve the general case as perfect groups includes a simple quatient in the maximal subnormal series.

Comment: Any finite group can be embedded as a subgroup of a perfect group, for example $A_n$ for large enough $n$. Could we embed any finite group as a normal subgroup of some perfect group? If so, then I think there is no such condition that you are looking for.

Comment: @spin: You cannot, for example, embed $S_3$ as a normal subgroup of a perfect group since $S_3 \unlhd G \Rightarrow G/C_G(S_3)) \cong S_3$.

Comment: If we know $B$ is subnormal (or even normal in $H$) and $B$ is perfect, must $H$ be perfect? This would be close to some true statements about components.

Comment: Any group that is generated by perfect subgroups is perfect, so $B$ perfect implies $H$ perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if there is a general answer. If $G$ would be *simple* then it is obviously true. If $H$ is a non-trivial abelian normal subgroup, then it is false: example $G=SL(2,5)$ and $B=H=Z(G)\cong C_2$.

Comment: Letting $G_2 = G \wr G = \operatorname{SL}(2,5) \wr \operatorname{SL}(2,5)$ also has some disturbing possibilities. It has normal subgroups $K \leq L$ such that $K$ is perfect and $L$ is not, so even when $B$ is non-solvable, we have no guarantee $H$ is perfect.